# Import function works in IDLE but not as an exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to import data from .py files, but when I run my game as an exe (I used pyinstaller to make my game into an exe), It dosen't work. I dont get an error or anything, it just dosent import the data. The weird thing is that when running this from IDLE, it works perfectly fine.

```
def achivementcheck():
    f = open("simplesavedata.py", "w")
    f.write("achivements = " + str(achivements) + "\n")
    f.close()

def option_save():
    f = open("optiondata.py", "w")
    f.write("volume = " + str(volume))
    f.close

from simplesavedata import *
from optiondata import *
```

EDIT: My game code

```
import random
import pickle
import os
from just_playback import Playback
import sys
playback = Playback()


init(convert=True)


volume = 0
achivements = 0
achivename = 0


def achivementcheck():
    f = open("simplesavedata.py", "w")
    f.write("achivements = " + str(achivements) + "\n")
    f.write("achivename = " + str(achivename) + "\n")
    f.close()

def option_save():
    f = open("optiondata.py", "w")
    f.write("volume = " + str(volume))
    f.close


#load saved data
from simplesavedata import *
from optiondata import *


playback.load_file("music/titlescreen.mp3")
playback.play()
playback.loop_at_end(True)

name = input("What is your name? ")

if name == "test":
     print("Test achivement")
     achivements += 1
     achivename += 1
     achivementcheck():

print("achivements = ", achivements)
print(gotten achivename", achivename, "times")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below and using `pyinstaller -F filename.py` the executable seems to work perfectly.  Make sure you are actually calling your functions so the code executes before trying to import the newly created python files.

`optiondata.json`

```
{
    "achievement": 0,
    "volume": 0
}
```

```
import json

def get_achievements():
    with open("optiondata.json", "rt") as jsonfile:
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
        achievements = data["achievements"]
    return achievements

def save_achievements(value):
    with open("optiondata.json", "rt") as jsonfile:
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
    with open("optiodata.json", "wt") as jsonfile:
        data["achievements"] = value
        json.dump(jsonfile)

def save_volume(value):
    with open("optiondata.json", "rt") as jsonfile:
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
    with open("optiondata.json", "wt") as jsonfile:
        data["volume"] = value
        json.dump(jsonfile)

def get_volume():
    with open("optiondata.json", "rt") as jsonfile:
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
    return data['volume']
```

Comment: Mine dosent seem to work at all. In simplesavedata.py, I can see that achievements is set to 12, and yet running the game it says I have 0 achievements. Actually, the exe seems to work fine even if I delete simplesavedata.py

Comment: @user19901195  that is because the exe creates the `simplesavedata.py` in code so no matter what it will always create a new simplesavedata.py

Comment: @user19901195  I hope you understand that both your option_save and achivementcheck functions are completely overwriting whatever was in the files they are writing too. So after you run option_save()  `"achivements = " + str(achivements) + "\n"`  is the entire contents of simplesavedata.py

Comment: I do understand that. So how would I get the exe to not create `simplesavedata.py` inside of it?

Comment: @user19901195  I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you post the actual game code?

Comment: I edited my code into the original post

Comment: I still don't understand what the purpose of simplesavedata and optiondata is...

Comment: savedata is supposed to save the achievements that you've unlocked, and optiondata is supposed to save your settings (altough I dont have any settings or achievements at the moments)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to save them in a .py file.  You are better off using a text file or a json file

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @user19901195  I would show by integrating it into your code but you don't show how you are using the values in your example, so I don't really know how to work it in but I will try

Comment: @user19901195  see my updated answer.  That shows how you can get the achievement value, or save a new new one and the same with the volume value